# pl/pgsql - How to create a table from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, create-table

I want to create a table `random_record` that takes in the same columns as another table `simulated_records`; one of the columns is `grade`. But I keep getting this error:

> ERROR:  "random_record.grade" is not a known variable
>   LINE 45:  random_record.grade = c_grade;
>             ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: "random_record.grade" is not a known variable
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 1635

```
FOR i IN 1..6 LOOP

    CREATE TABLE random_record AS 
    SELECT ....

    IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN

    .....

    END IF;


....

END LOOP;
```

I am not sure if I am properly creating the table.

Comment: refer this link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtableas.html

Comment: I think you want a `CASE ... WHEN` as part of the `CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT ...`

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks, this helped me figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you created table well, but the table is not a variable, so line

  ```
  IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN
  ```

  has not any sense. It is hard to identify, what you want, because using table in this context has not any value.
- creating in table in cycle has another issue - the statement `CREATE TABLE` will work only in first loop of cycle. Second loop has to fail, because table exists already.

It is hard help, because this code is messy - it is mixing variables, tables together, and it is not possible. Every object has own dimension, own access methods, and these mechanisms are different.